# Copy cell with header from datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I want to copy a cell from a datagridview with the columnheader. (Not the row header).

I tried this, but i get an exception:

```
if (dataGridView1.GetCellCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected) > 0)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in dataGridView1.Columns)
    {
        c.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
    }

    dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridviewSelectionMode.ColumnHeaderSelect;                 //only the column headers will be copied
    dataGridView1.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableWithAutoHeaderText;   //.EnableWithAutoHeaderText;
                                                                                                                                // Add the selection to the clipboard.
    Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataGridView1.GetClipboardContent());  //Here it goes wrong
}
```

This is the Exception i get. GetClipbooard content is empty ?

```
System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: data'

System.ArgumentNullException occurred
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: data
  Source=System.Windows.Forms



StackTrace:
   at System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetDataObject(Object data, Boolean copy, Int32 retryTimes, Int32 retryDelay)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetDataObject(Object data)
   at Q_ProtoType.FormMain.MenuItemNew_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Data\Programma\Development\VSSource - oefen_new_functions\Q_ProtoType\Q_ProtoType\FormMain.cs:line 895
   at System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem.MenuItemData.Execute()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Command.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Command.DispatchID(Int32 id)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCommand(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at Q_ProtoType.Program.Main() in c:\Data\Programma\Development\VSSource - oefen_new_functions\Q_ProtoType\Qx_ProtoType\Program.cs:line 42
```

Comment: Show us the exception then

Comment: I edit the question and added the exception

Comment: Did you added the exception? Where is it?

Answer (score 2):

You have set `ColumnHeaderSelect` to `FullColumnSelect`. So when calling [`GetClipboardContent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.getclipboardcontent(v=vs.110).aspx) you should have at least one column selected, otherwise you will receive a null value as clipboard content and [`ClipBoard.SetDataObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5b8kt5z4(v=vs.110).aspx) will throw an `ArgumentNullException`.

You can use `dataGridView1.SelectAll();` to select all columns if you want to export them all or for example if you want to select the first column, you can set `dataGridview1.Columns[0].Selected = true;`.